# HTML5 & Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I know nothing about javascript. Just want to tweak a chunk of code a little bit, but couldn't find answers on the net, or at least one that i can understand. Hope you can help me out.

It's an onMouseover/onClick javascript (plays audio) event for HTML5. The HEAD part of the script says in one place:

---

```
<Script>
............
...........

}
    else{
        return {playclip:function(){throw new Error("Your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio unfortunately")}}
    }
```

---

In other words, as best as I can understand, this means if the User's browser doesn't support HTML5 audio, the script will return this error message/dialog: "*Your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio unfortunately*".

But, I don't want this error message/dialog to be returned/generated/thrown whatever! Instead, I would prefer greatly the script to send the User automatically, before it shows any error message whatsoever, to a NEW non-HTML5 javascriptless plain webpage.

What can I do?

Comment: So, change the `function`, and make it do something else.  `return {playclip:function(){ alert('hi'); }}`

Answer (score 1):

you could do

```
window.location.href = "myhtml.html";
```

to direct to a new site immediately instead of the line "return..."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If the "myhtml.html" is in the same folder/directory as this file (with this javascript) is in, can I then write only the html filename, like we can do in HTML, or do I have to write the full URL of the "myhtml.html" here? (I can't check the "only the html filename" option at this moment since I don't have an older browser).

Comment: in my example i am using relative path. You can use absolute path too.
So direct answer is yes. You can just write the filename if the calling file is inside the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

Your else statement returns an object with one property (called `playclip`) which is a function that throws an error. If you'd like to redirect the user to another page instead, simply do a redirect instead of throwing an error:

```
else {
    return {
        playclip: function() {
            // it might be nice to tell a user why they're being redirected:
            alert('You are being redirected to another page because your browser does not support HTML5 audio!');
            window.location.href = 'whateverPageYouWant.html';
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If the 'whateverPageYouWant.html' is in the same folder/directory as this file (with this javascript) is in, can I then write only the html filename, like we can do in HTML, or do I have to write the full URL of the 'whateverPageYouWant.html' here? (I can't check the "only the html filename" option at this moment since I don't have an older browser).

Comment: @Mon just the file name should suffice - if you don't provide a host in a URL, the browser uses the current host.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest thing to do is change the location to another url.

```
else {
    window.location = 'http://newnonhtml5webpage/';
}
```